# Why is ffmpeg changing framerate from 60 to 120?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm using ffmpeg from powershell as 
`ffmpeg.exe -i i.mp4 o.mp4 -crf 22` and the video frame rate is changed from 59.99 to 120 for some reason. Any ideas why this is happening and how to use the source frame rate without setting it to a number with `-r`?

I get the below report before the encoding:

```
ffmpeg version N-83781-g3016e91 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavcodec     57. 82.102 / 57. 82.102
  libavformat    57. 66.103 / 57. 66.103
  libavdevice    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavfilter     6. 74.100 /  6. 74.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'i.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
  Duration: 00:15:00.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 31455 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 1920x1080, 31431 kb/s, 59.99 fps, 120 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 15 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 00000000053af4e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 00000000053af4e0] profile High, level 5.1
[libx264 @ 00000000053af4e0] 264 - core 148 r2762 90a61ec - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'o.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.66.103
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 120 fps, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.82.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.82.102 aac
```

Comment: `Any ideas why this is happening` - Most likely because ffmpeg is unable to read out the "proper" frame rate / it is saved in a non-standard way into the metadata. `how to use the source frame rate without setting it to a number with -r?` - No, as that is what the `-r`-option is for, in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`59.99 fps, 120 tbr`  --> The file looks to be variable frame rate. Although the average rate is 59.99 fps, the peak frame rate is 120 fps. FFmpeg's MP4 muxer, by default, writes constant frame rate files. In doing so, it will aim to preserve the peak rate so no frames are dropped. In those regions of the stream where frame rate is lower than the peak rate, it will duplicate frames to match the peak rate. Of course, this leads to massive duplication of frames if the difference is high.

You can disable this behaviour by changing the video sync method.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i i.mp4 -vsync 0 -crf 22 -c:a copy o.mp4
```

- `-vsync 0` changes the video sync method to passthrough, which suppresses frame duplication.
- `-c:a copy` remuxes the audio, skipping re-encoding.